# What is the meaning of this TFS Icon?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, tfs-2015

I have been looking all over and cannot figure out what this icon represents. I have gone through numerous questions on SO and on Microsoft's website.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245455.aspx
 - No information on this icon

I am on TFS 2015 and Visual Studio 2015.
The icon in question is the one that looks like yellow papers with with the 4 dots.

[image: Example of icon]

[image: Example with larger scope]

Comment: What context is the screenshot from?

Comment: @chief7 It is from the local side of the Source Control Explorer. I added a screenshot to show the server side as well.

Comment: I've never seen that icon and I can't find it in VS anywhere.  I also use VS2015 and TFS2015.

Comment: @chief7 Exactly why my entire team is so confused.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do these Multi-Document like TFS Icons Mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49036924/what-do-these-multi-document-like-tfs-icons-mean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If file is **branched to more than one location** its icon is changed to icon as this.

I was wondering if you or your mates have installed *TFS Source Control Explorer* Extension. Please also check this link for detail information: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8ad891d2-142b-4acf-b487-46db9f3bb5cf