# What do these Multi-Document like TFS Icons Mean?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, version-control, icons

Does anyone know what these icons mean in TFS 2017 Source Control Explorer? The files are .cpp and .h... The icons for the two newly added files show up correctly (as seen below), but the existing files all turn into the multi-yellow-document... why is it replacing the icon for file type?

[image]

The icons initially load correctly, but seem to change after being analyzed...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If file is **branched to more than one location** its icon is changed to icon as this.

> **File icon change**
>
> In the file list on the left side of **Source Control Explorer**
>   window are **branched files** displayed with changed icon.

[image]

I was wondering if you or your mates have installed *TFS Source Control Explorer* Extension. Please also check this [**link**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HolanJan.TFSSourceControlExplorerExtension-13343) for more detail information：

Comment: Brilliant, yes indeed I had TFS Source Control Explorer Extension installed. Uninstalling it removed the problem, if you call it a problem. To be clear, the icon only appears if I branch a folder under an already existing branch, so a branch within a branch. The problem is that apparently there is an artifact of this that can't be undone (I suspect from the creation of the logical branch structure), and that icon quite annoyingly hangs on to that artifact. So even if I delete all branches, convert to folder, or unroll all branching, that icon sticks around.

Comment: The icon even sticks around with a complete delete of all previous branches and a delete and re-add of the parent folder.  The only way to remove the icon is by renaming/moving the folder, or apparently by using destroy to destroy the branches.

Answer (score 2):

I just came across a more specific solution than uninstalling all of the TFS Source Control Explorer Extension. The "icon change" functionality that is causing this can be optionally toggled on its own from Tools->Options. Set "Files icon change" = False to disable this icon behavior.

[image]